# Xorg segfault after pressing volume buttons on thinkpad / Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: xorg, 22.04, thinkpad, function-keys

Occasionally when pressing the volume function buttons (volume up, down, or mute) on my thinkpad P14S, Xorg will crash and restart. It only happens sometimes when pressing these buttons, so it's hard to reproduce, but it has happened dozens of times now over the past few weeks. It has only ever happened when pressing the volume function buttons, but I don't use the other function buttons much so maybe they would do it too.

If anyone knows of a fix or has suggestions on troubleshooting I'd be grateful.

/var/log/syslog from the most recent crash:

```
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt krunner[12952]: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt baloorunner[3218]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt at-spi-bus-launcher[2214]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt kactivitymanagerd[2518]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2374]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt krunner[3382]: X IO Error
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt kglobalaccel5[2464]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt pulseaudio[1800]: X11 I/O error handler called
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt kscreen_backend_launcher[2699]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt krunner[3121]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt pulseaudio[1800]: X11 I/O error exit handler called, preparing to tear down X11 modules
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kscreen.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kscreen.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kscreen.service: Consumed 1.677s CPU time.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service: Consumed 15.417s CPU time.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-baloorunner.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-baloorunner.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-baloorunner.service: Consumed 2.138s CPU time.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kglobalaccel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kglobalaccel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-kglobalaccel.service: Consumed 2.981s CPU time.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Consumed 1.408s CPU time.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: app-libreoffice\x2dcalc-0be6c2a4c8d043c6b2df1211e136ac36.scope: Consumed 1min 23.739s CPU time.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 11:18:16 basalt systemd[1790]: plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service: Consumed 3.672s CPU time.
```

Xorg log:

```
[ 12405.022] (EE)
[ 12405.022] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 12405.030] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x56533b89c6e9]
[ 12405.031] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x7f94c2882520]
[ 12405.031] (EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (NewCurrentScreen+0x1b9) [0x56533b7311e9]
[ 12405.031] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (MaybeDeliverEventsToClient+0x4d5) [0x56533b732c85]
[ 12405.031] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (MaybeDeliverEventsToClient+0x9d3) [0x56533b733183]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WindowsRestructured+0x163) [0x56533b734183]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitProximityClassDeviceStruct+0x1fdd) [0x56533b812a7d]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (XkbHandleActions+0x1dc) [0x56533b83ce4c]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (XkbRemoveResourceClient+0x7c1) [0x56533b835f21]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (XkbRemoveResourceClient+0x9be) [0x56533b83611e]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (TimerSet+0x170) [0x56533b895c60]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0x258) [0x56533b895ee8]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x117) [0x56533b726257]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3c4) [0x56533b72a524]
[ 12405.032] (EE) 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_init_first+0x90) [0x7f94c2869d90]
[ 12405.033] (EE) 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f94c2869e40]
[ 12405.033] (EE) 16: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x25) [0x56533b7135f5]
[ 12405.033] (EE)
[ 12405.033] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x7ffe4d70f000
[ 12405.033] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 12405.033] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[ 12405.033] (EE)
[ 12405.033] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[ 12405.033] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 12405.033] (EE)
[ 12405.033] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 12405.103] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: I too seem to be hitting this. Have you made any progress? I think possibly my system was under a high load at the time because I see these right before the crash:
[358279.146] (EE) event4  - Logitech MX Master 2S: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 33ms, your system is too slow